# Sync between two TextViews

Tags: android, html, textview

I have two Textviews (A and B) that display HTML text. They have the same text, but different text size.
Can I do the following:
Scroll textview A, and when it stops, texview B will show the same paragraph?
In same context - can I use HTML bookmarks (IDs)?

P.S. I do not want to use Webviews!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options, if I understand correctly:

1) When scroll stops, just change the text size of the current TextView, don't use two...

2) Keep both TextViews (in ScrollViews), but keep one View.GONE at all times.  Scroll on one, then when you want to switch, you can call scrollTo() on the inactive one, and switch it to View.VISIBLE (and the inactive one is GONE).

3) Similar to the above, but use 2 TextViews per paragraph, it should prevent you from doing a scrollTo() which could get tricky with different size fonts.

Comment: Matt, thanks, but I'm not sure you understood what I wanted. I want the two textviews to show same paragraph on both of them. Thing is - they have diferent text size, so scroll is different. How to I get them to scroll to same location\paragraph?